# Use built-in categories for custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress

Can we use built-in categories for the custom post types. and how can I access the category page(url) for new custom post types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real solution is to setup CTP slug to "slug/%category%"

Then updating the CPT permalink
(put following code in functions.php)

```
add_filter('post_link', 'category_permalink', 1, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'category_permalink', 1, 3);


function category_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
    //con %category% catturo il rewrite del Custom Post Type
    if (strpos($permalink, '%category%') === FALSE) return $permalink;
        // Get post
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        if (!$post) return $permalink;

        // Get taxonomy terms
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'category');
        if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0]))
            $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
        else $taxonomy_slug = 'no-category';

    return str_replace('%category%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
}
```

On the top of category.php, add a check

```
$segments = explode('/', trim(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH), '/'));
//print_r($segments);
if($segments[1] == 'CPT Slug'){ //Change CPT Slug to your own slug
//Show CPT posts
}else{
//General posts
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can add built in categories to custom post type.

Just add below code into `functions.php` file

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_category_taxonomy_to_custom_post' );
function add_category_taxonomy_to_custom_post() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'custom_post' );
}
```

where `custom_post` is the Post Type Key.

Comment: Thanks. can you please tell me how can i show custom posts by category on separate page. Lets say i have CPT “talent” and a category “art”. I have two different posts one is created under CPT “talents” and other is general post created under “posts”. Both posts are assigned to “art” category(this is common for both CPT and general posts). Now i know that for the general posts you can view the category page as http://domain.com/category/art/. For CPT category page i guess the url should be http://domain.com/talent/art/ but it is giving me 404 error.

Comment: Use `http://domain.com/category/art` for default/general posts and use `http://domain.com/category/art/?post_type=talents` for CPT

Answer (score 0):

Use built-in categories for custom post types